# Removing stop words with dplyr

Tags: r

Reading http://tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html states :

> "
>
> Often in text analysis, we will want to remove stop words; stop words
>   are words that are not useful for an analysis, typically extremely
>   common words such as “the”, “of”, “to”, and so forth in English. We
>   can remove stop words (kept in the tidytext dataset stop_words) with
>   an anti_join().
>
> data(stop_words)
>
> tidy_books <- tidy_books %>%   anti_join(stop_words)
>
> "

I'm attempting to modify to remove stop words from a string :

```
data(stop_words)
str_v <- paste(c("this is a test"))
str_v <- str_v %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)
```

but returns error :

```
Error in UseMethod("anti_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Do need to convert str_v to class that contains method `anti_join` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `str_v` is a vector.  It needs to be converted to a data.frame or `tibble` using `as.tibble`, then with `unnest_tokens` the 'value' column is split up into words while renaming it as 'word', so that when we do the `anti_join` the common columns match up and join by 'word'

```
library(tidytext)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
str_v %>%
    as.tibble %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, value) %>%
    anti_join(stop_words)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#   word
#  <chr>
#1  test
```